# Disabling an element from being clicked after it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that saves the content that a user edits. I do not want them to hit the save button multiple times because of the load it causes on the server. I want to disable the button after they click on it.
Here is what I have attempted(doesn't work, though):

```
  var active = true;
  $("#save").click(function() {
    if (!active) return;
    active = false;
........
........
........
    active = true;
```

The problem is that the user can still click on the element multiple times.
How can I fix this problem?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to enable the click after the onclick code has finished executing.

Comment: is `#save` an `<input type="button" />`?

Comment: In your code, you seem to make active true again, which would allow them to click again... so remove that last line and it should work?

Comment: No, it is a div. The three lines of dots are my code. I only want the button to be clickable again after the true lines of code are executed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#save").one('click', function() {
    //this function will be called only once even after clicking multiple times
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to enable the function after the code has executed.

Comment: You can again set the handler using "one" once the required code is executed and you feel now the event shud be attached again. Thanks

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `$("#save").one('click', function() {...` I see **13** upvotes but...

Answer (score 2):

There is a `disabled` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/uM9Md/.

```
  $("#save").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true)
........
........
........
    $(this).attr('disabled', false)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind the click handler, but I would go with `.one` as per @ShankarSangoli's answer (+1).

```
$("#save").click(function() {

    // do things

    $(this).unbind("click");

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1):

If the element is an input you can do this really easily:

```
<input name="BUTTON" type="submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="document.BUTTON.disabled = true;">
```

That's some handy HTML Javascript integration stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
<input type="button" id="save" ... />
```

You can either do:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var $save = $(this);

    //
    // save code
    //

    $save.get(0).disabled = true;
});
```

Which disabled the button natively, or you can use jQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) functionality:

```
$('#save').one('click',function(){
    //
    // save code
    //
});
```

Which will only execute once and must be re-bound. (But if you're deciding to enable/disable based on parameters, using the [disabled attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) is probably a better choice.)