# disable link after innitial click and enable when ajax-request is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking several times on the link run several ajax-requests. That is why it is hang browser will and is run code js bad. how can to disable link after innitial click and enable when ajax-request is finished?
With respect

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url, function(){
                $(this).hide().show();
                $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
            })
            //.hide().show("slow")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at this


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752025/disabling-an-element-from-being-clicked-after-it-is-clicked/6752054#6752054][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752025/disabling-an-element-from-being-clicked-after-it-is-clicked/6752054#6752054

Comment: Does it have to be a link? You could use a button, it has a 'disabled' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

change link to # after clicking

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.results').load(url, function(){
         $this.attr('href', href);
         $(this).hide().show();
         $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
    });
});
```

return it after ajax is done

Comment: In this case the ajax call is fired anyway because it's not related to the href (and he is preventing the default behaviour anyway)

Comment: well it's not. If href doesn't exist, it DOES not fire

Answer (score 0):

well you could hide it and show it back after the call has finished:

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');
        //hide it
        $(id).hide();
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url, function(){
                //show it 
                $(id).show();
                $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
            })
            //.hide().show("slow")
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the link disabled:

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');

        // disable the link
        $(id).removeAttr("href");

        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url, function(){
                $(this).hide().show();
                $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
            })

        });

        // enable the link again
        $(id).attr("href", url);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#YourLinkId').click(function() {
    // Your ajax code
    return false; // Disable the link
});
```