# Live mouseenter and mouseleave with exceptions

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

My code is working fine but I don't want it to fire when `#stem` and `#case` are hovered over, because they are part of the animation. (They are absolutely positioned over `div_mainGraphic`). Anyone have any ideas?

```
$('#div_mainGraphic').live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "-=35px"}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "+=35px"}, 150);
    }
});
```

Is the code that is working and I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$('#div_mainGraphic').live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "-=35px"}, 500);
    }
    if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "+=35px"}, 150);
    }
    if (event.location == '???') {
        ???
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="div_mainGraphic">
</div>
<img src="/images/img_stem.png" id="stem" />
<img src="/images/img_case.png" id="case" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this along with your code, this will basically stop the event propagation on hover.

```
$("#stem,  #case").hover(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Use this code of yours

```
$('#div_mainGraphic').live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "-=35px"}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#stem').animate({"top": "+=35px"}, 150);
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can also try to move #stem and #case elements into #div_mainGraphic since they are absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it...but it is making me think that it should be something like that. Did that work for you? Does it matter which comes first?

Comment: Since #stem and #case are absolute positioned elements can you append them into #div_mainGraphic? This way the the mouseenter and mouseleave will still trigger the same event when you hove on them.

Comment: you mean move them inside or make them part of the selector of the #div_mainGraphic? thanks

Comment: ok great that worked! now would you know anything about the .one() property? so it wouldn't allow them to overlap animations?

Comment: `one` is used to attach any event handler which unbinds itself after triggering once. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752025/disabling-an-element-from-being-clicked-after-it-is-clicked/6752054#6752054

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely simple and readable solution in my code:

```
$('.free').live('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('.alert').fadeIn(200);
});

$('.free').live('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('.alert').fadeOut(200);
});
```