# Click event more than once, but unbind after each click

Tags: jquery, rows

What I want to do: Every time I click a table row it goes into edit mode. When I click another row, the row I clicked previously exits edit mode and the one I just clicked goes into edit mode.

The following code is in an included JavaScript file. I have a function that makes table rows editable.

```
function editRow(row) {
    /* awesome code here */
}
```

and have the events ready...

```
$(".editable_title").click(function() {
    editRow(this.parentNode);
});`
```

What I have tried:

1. Put the code in between `$(document).ready(function() { });` but it only works with the first click and the first edit submission. But then, if I try to do it again, it just doesn't work.
2. Just put the code by itself in the included file without the `$(document).ready(function(){ });`. Then use `onclick` events on the tr's. Problem:

   1. The JavaScript is intrusive.
   2. If I click on the same row more than once, it keeps on triggering the event multiple times; and if I click in different rows, all of them go into edit mode at the same time.

I know it's just a matter of having an constant event listener and using unbind. I tried using `.live()` which worked well but then I couldn't get `.die()` to work.

Can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this. This is what you are looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752025/disabling-an-element-from-being-clicked-after-it-is-clicked/6752054#6752054

Comment: Thanks @ShankarSangoli but I tried `.one` but then what about after I submit the Update button? I can't make any more rows go into edit more.

Comment: You can again call `one` and attach the handler.

Comment: How can I do that? You mean I try to call it again by clicking on the row again? It only works once.

Comment: Have you thought about adding a function that exits edit mode, which is called as the first thing on `$(".editable_title").click()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".editable_title").one(function() {
    editRow(this);
});

function editRow(row) {
    var rowNode = row.parentNode;
    /* awesome code here */


    //Attach the click event here again after editing is done
    //If you are doing any ajax calls then this should be done in the success callback
    $(row).one(function() {
       editRow(this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead of `click`:

```
$('.editable_title').one('click', function() { editRow(this.parentNode); });
```

And then use `one` again on just the `.editable_title` for the row you edited when you're done editing.

Or you could use a flag:

```
$('.editable_title').click(function() {
    var $p = $(this).parent();
    if($p.data('editing'))
        return;
    $p.data('editing', true);
    editRow($p[0]);
});
```

And then do a [`$x.removeData('editing')`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData), for the appropriate `$x`, when you're done editing.

Comment: Thanks @mu but how can I use `.one` more than once?

Comment: @leonel: You'd have to call it again (but just for the single `.editable_title` that you're interested in) when you're done editing.

Comment: How can I call it again? I don't understand. I can probably do a `onclick()` event on the link, but that would be obtrusive javascript. Or do you think that's the way to go?

Comment: @leonel: You'd just call `$(x).one('click', function() { editRow(this.parentNode); });` on the appropriate `x`, probably `$(e).closest('tr').find('.editable_title').one(...` where `e` is the thing passed to `editRow`.

Comment: I would go with flag solution.